# How do I assign values for more than 1 field of a database to check boxes?

Tags: c#

I want to show some values from my database on a Windows Forms Application in c#. So far, I have read in the database to an ArrayList and I have assigned checkboxes to each item. Now, I want the checkboxes to display the product name as well as the price which is in a different field. I am having trouble with this because when I include the Price field, the assignments are changing. Please assist me.
This is the code that I have:

```
private void Customer_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = connection;
            command.CommandText = "SELECT [Product Name], [Price] FROM Cakes";
            List<string> Cakes = new List<string>();
            using (OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while(reader.Read())
                {
                    Cakes.Add(reader["Product Name"].ToString());
                    Cakes.Add(reader["Price"].ToString()); 
                }
            }
            checkBox1.Text = Cakes[0];
            checkBox2.Text = Cakes[1];
            checkBox3.Text = Cakes[2];
            checkBox4.Text = Cakes[3];
            checkBox5.Text = Cakes[4];
            checkBox16.Text = Cakes[5];
            connection.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error " + ex);
        }
        

    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.
Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add only one cake instead of two per each reader cycle:

```
Cakes.Add(reader["Product Name"].ToString() + " " + reader ["Price" ].ToString());
```